# Migrate from Java layout to LayoutInflater for ListView item

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**First post!** :-D

So I am currently forking an older app, and I want to update a ListView layout.

I have created a great-looking XML file, but how do I incorporate it into the list when the strings are put in the layout file, which is a class that extends LinearLayout; instead of in the adapter.

Can I do the same with a LayoutInflater? Because I do **not** want to redesign this in Java because I spent an hour trying to get this layout aesthetically pleasing (besides, I do not know how to do a layout properly in Java.)

I am on mobile, I will post full code on my laptop if I have to.

I would show you the screenshot of the layout preview, but I am on the app, and I can not attach pictures. If I get a chance, I will attach the pic when I am on my laptop.
For now, cheezy 90s ASCII art.

```
______________________________

| 9:20 AM        [ OFF | ON ] |

| Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat |

| —(o)————————————————————————|

|-----------------------------|
```

My XML  layout file, truncated.

**schedule_list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:paddingBottom="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"> 
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <SeekBar .... />
    <LinearLayout ...>
        <Switch ... />
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

A chunk of the LinearLayout Java file:

**ScheduleView.java**

```
public class ScheduleView extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView mActive;
...
      /*
      * active
      */

    mActive = new TextView(context);
    mActive.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    mActive.setText(schedule.isActive() ? "ACTIVE" : "INACTIVE");
    mActive.setTextColor(schedule.isActive() ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
    activeDaysRow.addView(mActive);
```

And how it is referenced in the ListAdapter:

**ScheduleListAdapter.java**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ScheduleView scheduleView;

    Schedule schedule = mItems.get(position);

    /*
     * if the View already exists, set its values; otherwise give it the Schedule to pull them itself
     */
    if (convertView != null &&
            convertView instanceof ScheduleView) {
        scheduleView = (ScheduleView) convertView;
        scheduleView.setFromSchedule(schedule);
    }
    else {
        scheduleView = new ScheduleView(mContext, schedule);
    }

    return scheduleView;
}
```

*Edit:* more of ScheduleView.java, and I am at the character limt...

```
public class ScheduleView extends LinearLayout {

private TextView mDay0;
private TextView mDay1;
private TextView mDay2;
private TextView mDay3;
private TextView mDay4;
private TextView mDay5;
private TextView mDay6;
private TextView mStartTime;
private SeekBar mVolume;
private int mVolumeType;
private TextView mVibrate;
private TextView mActive;

public ScheduleView(Context context, Schedule schedule) {
    super(context);

    mVolumeType = schedule.getVolumeType();

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);

    //convenience for addView calls later
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsWrapBoth = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsFillWrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    /*
     * setting data here *should* be faster than calling the setters; otherwise I'd just call them
     *  and keep any special field-display logic there
     */

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
    tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(1, true);

    TableRow activeDaysRow = new TableRow(context);

    mActive = new TextView(context);
    mActive.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    mActive.setText(schedule.isActive() ? "ACTIVE" : "INACTIVE");
    mActive.setTextColor(schedule.isActive() ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
    activeDaysRow.addView(mActive);

    LinearLayout daysLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    daysLayout.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    daysLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    mDay0 = new TextView(context);
    mDay0.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay0.setText(schedule.isDay0() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day0) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay0, paramsWrapBoth);
    mDay1 = new TextView(context);
    mDay1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay1.setText(schedule.isDay1() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day1) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay1, paramsWrapBoth);
    mDay2 = new TextView(context);
    mDay2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay2.setText(schedule.isDay2() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day2) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay2, paramsWrapBoth);
    mDay3 = new TextView(context);
    mDay3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay3.setText(schedule.isDay3() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day3) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay3, paramsWrapBoth);
    mDay4 = new TextView(context);
    mDay4.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay4.setText(schedule.isDay4() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day4) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay4, paramsWrapBoth);
    mDay5 = new TextView(context);
    mDay5.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay5.setText(schedule.isDay5() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day5) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay5, paramsWrapBoth);
    mDay6 = new TextView(context);
    mDay6.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    mDay6.setText(schedule.isDay6() ? getContext().getText(R.string.day6) : "   ");
    daysLayout.addView(mDay6, paramsWrapBoth);
    activeDaysRow.addView(daysLayout);

    tableLayout.addView(activeDaysRow);

    TableRow timeRow = new TableRow(context);

    TextView startTimeLabel = new TextView(context);
    startTimeLabel.setPadding(2, 2, 10, 2);
    startTimeLabel.setText(R.string.startTimeLabel);
    timeRow.addView(startTimeLabel);

    mStartTime = new TextView(context);
    mStartTime.setTextSize(18);
    mStartTime.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    mStartTime.setText(formatTime(schedule.getStartHour(), schedule.getStartMinute()));
    timeRow.addView(mStartTime);

    tableLayout.addView(timeRow);

    TableRow volumeRow = new TableRow(context);

    TextView volumeLabel = new TextView(context);
    volumeLabel.setPadding(2, 7, 2, 2);
    volumeLabel.setText(R.string.volumeLabel);
    volumeRow.addView(volumeLabel);

    SeekBar mVolume = new SeekBar(context);
    mVolume.setEnabled(false);
    mVolume.setFocusable(false);
    mVolume.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    mVolume.setClickable(false);
    mVolume.setPadding(2, 2, 7, 2);
    mVolume.setMax(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(mVolumeType));
    mVolume.setProgress(schedule.getVolume());

    TableRow.LayoutParams volumeLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    volumeLayoutParams.span = 2;
    volumeRow.addView(mVolume, volumeLayoutParams);

    tableLayout.addView(volumeRow);

    TableRow vibrateRow = new TableRow(context);

    TextView vibrateLabel = new TextView(context);
    vibrateLabel.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    vibrateLabel.setText(R.string.vibrateLabel);
    vibrateRow.addView(vibrateLabel);

    mVibrate = new TextView(context);
    mVibrate.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    mVibrate.setText(schedule.isVibrate() ? "On" : "Off");
    vibrateRow.addView(mVibrate);

    if (mVolumeType == AudioManager.STREAM_RING ||
            mVolumeType == AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) {
        tableLayout.addView(vibrateRow, paramsFillWrap);
    }

    addView(tableLayout, paramsFillWrap);
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to inflate a layout in the adapter rather than using the ScheduleView class because you've created a layout descriptor for the ScheduleView display?  If my understanding is correct then you will need to replace 
`scheduleView = new ScheduleView(mContext, schedule);`
with something like
    `scheduleView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_view, parent, false);`

If my understanding is correct let me know and I will provide a fuller answer.

Comment: Yes but the data is accessed from a different class, and in the layout file it literally does setText and such instead of using a proper list adapter.

Comment: The data you are displaying is passed in to the ScheduleView class as an instance of Schedule.  From your ListAdapter snippet it looks as if you pass an array/list of Schedules into the ListAdapter as mItems, so you can populate your layout fields using that data.

Comment: There is an ArrayList variable in ScheduleListAdapter `private ArrayList<Schedule> mItems = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
` but I suck at Java and do not know how to use it.

Comment: The original source code for the files are at [this folder on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/app-soundmanager/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Froozen%2FSoundManagerv2%2Fschedule)